# Windows qemu how to create multiple TAP-Windows Adapter V9?

Tags: windows, networking, bridge, qemu

1. I installed qemu on my Windows 10 PC.
2. I installed openvpn tap-win32 driver on my PC, after installation, there is a TAP-Windows Adapter V9 in the system
   [image]

3.I used this command to start a ubuntu VM.

`qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -vga virtio -show-cursor -usb -device usb-tablet -accel hax -drive file=ubuntu-temp.qcow2,if=virtio -net nic -net tap,ifname="Local Area Connection",script=no,downscript=no`

4. enable internet sharing in my ethernet adapter, then the tap-windows adapter's ip is automatically set to 192.168.137.1/24.
   [image]
5. I log in to my ubuntu VM, and configure static ip 192.168.137.101/24, now the VM has internet access. All works right.

My question is, what if I want to start more than one VM, should I create more tap-windows adapters? Or is there a better way?